# PHP Find a maximum average for 10 subsequent numbers in a list of 50 random numbers

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm working on this for quite a while, but I don't know how to fix this:

I have a list of 50 random numbers, and when 10 subsequent numbers from this this (numbers 11-20 for example, or numbers 24-33) reach an average of x, I want to get a notification.

The 50 numbers are in 1 row of a (HTML) table, each in a different column.

Anybody with an idea how to start? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any code so far?

Comment: Is the data from your database (SQL), or from an external resource (HTML)? My first thought would be to find the average from (1 - 10, 2 - 11, 3 - 12, 4 - 13, and so on), and then you can compare it against *x*.

Comment: Please show what you tried. We're not here to do your work for you, we're here to help you fix the problems in your code.

Comment: Barmar: I know and no, I haven't got anything yet. It's because I didn't know how to start. If I get something to start with, I can build on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your numbers in an array, you can loop through the array in chunks of 10, and then find the maximum average.

```
<?php

$numbers = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1,
                 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 11, 12, //large numbers here
                 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1);

$number = 10; //numbers in a set

$max = 0;
$index = 0;

$size = sizeof($numbers) - $number;       
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    $tmp = array_sum(array_slice($numbers, $i, $number)) / $number;
    if ($tmp > $max) {
        $max = $tmp;
        $index = $i;
    }
}

echo "Largest set of " . $number . " numbers is: " . implode(', ', array_slice($numbers, $index, $number)) . "\nAverage of: " . $max;
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/de59994984f27c):

```
Largest set of 10 numbers is: 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11
Average of: 12.5
```

You can then compare the largest average to your threshold and notify yourself.

Comment: I think consecutive in his question means only +1,but I could be wrong.

Comment: Oh it was only by chance that the numbers in my array were ±1. I believe the OP is saying numbers in the array in which the indices are ±1.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thanks! Numbers may vary randomly between 2 and 30 or so. It has something to do with wind prediction and getting notifications when multiple days of (strong) winds occur at various places. I can now work with this example. Thanks you very much for the effort! I just didn't knew how to start!